# Locking the scroll(onmousewheel="false") in X3D model

Tags: javascript, html, x3d, x3dom

How do I lock the mousewheel in X3D model in html?

```
<x3d showStat="false" showLog="false" x="0px" y="0px" width='750px' height='600px'>
    <scene>
        <viewpoint position="0 0 0" orientation="1 1 1 2"></viewpoint>
        <matrixTransform id="teapotRotation">
            <Inline nameSpaceName="Deer" mapDEFToID="true" onclick='handleGroupClick(event);' url="new.x3d"/>
        </matrixTransform>
    </scene>
</x3d>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **NavigationInfo** to restrict the movement in the scene. The "**type**" parameter is what you need to use:
"EXAMINE" best for rotating solitary objects
"FLY" allows zooming in, out and around
"WALK" also allows exploration, but on the ground
"LOOKAT" use pointer to select geometry of interest
"ANY" lets user select any mode
"NONE" gives user zero control of navigation

Comment: Thanks @CpS! But I have tried, also used disableRightDrag="true" to restrict the scroll. It is useless yet! I tried in Safari, it should be implement in web sever, should it?